# Compilation error :: Bazel + TensorFlow. pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py doesn't exist or not a regular file

Tags: compilation, tensorflow

Bazel build crashes while building a python package on Ubuntu.
Full report:

```
sudo bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package /tmp/tensorflow_pkg
Tue Mar 14 02:41:24 IST 2017 : === Using tmpdir: /tmp/tmp.ZAETGIkAd2
~/git/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package.runfiles
~/git/tensorflow
~/git/tensorflow
/tmp/tmp.ZAETGIkAd2 ~/git/tensorflow
Tue Mar 14 02:41:26 IST 2017 : === Building wheel
error: can't copy 'tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py': doesn't exist or not a regular file
```

I have seen the earlier bug reports filed on this and have installed `swig` that is required for TensorFlow on Ubuntu. Still same error log.

System details

`uname -a` :

Linux - 3.13.0-107-generic

Comment: It looks like the Bazel build "succeeded", because the `build_pip_package` script is the output of the `bazel build` step. Do you see any logs from the `bazel build //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package` command?

Comment: Really stupid mistake. bazel build had failed. Please see solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely not a problem with the build_pip_package command. I had a failed `bazel build` command that I have erroneously overlooked.

Here is the error log:

```
ERROR: /home/annanay/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/9b62c7240de3d9136528cdded945b550/external/llvm/BUILD:418:5: Generating code from table: lib/Target/AArch64/AArch64.td @llvm//:aarch64_target_gen__gen_fast_isel_genrule failed: bash failed: error executing command 
(cd /home/annanay/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/9b62c7240de3d9136528cdded945b550/execroot/tensorflow && \
exec env - \
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin \
/bin/bash -c 'source external/bazel_tools/tools/genrule/genrule-setup.sh; bazel-out/host/bin/external/llvm/llvm-tblgen -I external/llvm/include -I external/llvm/tools/clang/include -I $(dirname external/llvm/lib/Target/AArch64/AArch64.td) -gen-fast-isel external/llvm/lib/Target/AArch64/AArch64.td -o bazel-out/local-opt/genfiles/external/llvm/lib/Target/AArch64/AArch64GenFastISel.inc'): com.google.devtools.build.lib.shell.BadExitStatusException: Process exited with status 127.
bazel-out/host/bin/external/llvm/llvm-tblgen: relocation error: bazel-out/host/bin/external/llvm/llvm-tblgen: symbol _ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE9_M_createERmm, version GLIBCXX_3.4.21 not defined in file libstdc++.so.6 with link time reference
Target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package failed to build
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change from build directory to some other directory.
This works for me.